# How can you display Non-Ascii characters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am doing this :

```
> "é"
```

Which is immediately converted and printed as this :

```
> "��"
=> "\xC3\xA9"
```

Where I would like it returned simply as :

```
=> "é"
```

I have readline-rb as a gem. It writes appropriately until I enter it in console, and the unicode prints appropriately in my terminal so I know that the problem exclusively exists only within the rails framework.

I have at the top of my file :

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8
```

But it's reproducible in console, and equally does not work there either.

Does anyone know how to make it auto-encode accented characters?

*Further troubled update*

```
> word
=> "allá"
> word == "all��"
=> false
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen in `irb`?

Comment: In irb, it acts as if readline is not installed. Where by if I type an accented é, the cursor will move a space ahead, and then return to its original space. Nothing printed.

Comment: It depends. What is your Ruby version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not interested in this anymore, but this is the solution i found, in case anyone else needs it.

```
value = "allá"
value.force_encoding('UTF-8').html_safe
```

With that the controller no longer raises an exception when trying to render the view :)